# Alfresco permission - acces other group documents after asking to unblock

Tags: permissions, alfresco

Hy Alfresco users!

I am new in Alfresco and I have a question .

If we have two groups of users (group1 and group2) . Every group have its documents.

Users from the group1 can access group1 documents , and can search through group2 documents (in fact through all documents on the repository).
They (group1) can see general search response (links returned) from Alfresco but can not open/read/download group2 documents .
They (group1) can ask for a special request from group2 members clicking on that link , that search returned.
If a member of group2 unblock that document , group1 can read/download/open that document.

Is it possible this in Alfresco , and what do I need to install (Alfresco version and web interface option )?
I have now already installed Alfresco 3.4 .

Thank you for support .

Horace

Answer (score 0):

Alfresco has a full-feature permission/ACL system. It would be possible to implement your requirements but "asking for permission via links" is not an OOTB feature of any Alfresco client/app that I know.

Start implementing your requirements(I would recommend Alfresco 4.2) & come back with a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) & not with a general general howto question.